When I try to run two classes in parallel in TestNG xml, second class gives error. But works if both classes are run individually
I am using POM by selenium java. While trying to run two classes in parallel with TestNG XML. I am facing this issue that the second class is not running properly. When I use @BeforeClass annotation, then with two different windows, the second class runs perfectly.
My whole Page Object Model page classes and test classes are given below
Base Page:
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class BasePage {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}

Login page:
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class LoginPage extends BasePage{
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    // sign in button locator
    @FindBy(css = ".login-btn")
    WebElement SetSignInBtn;

    // email locator
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='form-group label-up']//input[@type='text']")
    WebElement SetEmailField;

    // proceed btn locator
    @FindBy(css = ".form-group.text-center")
    WebElement SetProceedBtn;

    // password locator
    @FindBy(css = "input[type='password']")
    WebElement SetPass;

    // sign in button locator
    @FindBy(id = "sign_in_button")
    WebElement SignBtn;

    public void Login(String mail, String passWord){
        // sign in button click
        SetSignInBtn.click();

        // email field input
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(SetEmailField));
        SetEmailField.sendKeys(mail);
        // proceed button click
        SetProceedBtn.click();
        // pass field input
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(SetPass));
        SetPass.sendKeys(passWord);
        SignBtn.click();
    }
}

Recharge Page:
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import java.beans.Visibility;

public class RechargePage extends BasePage{
    public RechargePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(id = "typeahead-basic")
    WebElement mobileNumberField;

    @FindBy(id = "telecom-operator")
    WebElement selectOperator;

    @FindBy(id = "connection-type")
    WebElement connectionType;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@formcontrolname='amount']")
    WebElement amount;

    @FindBy(css = "button[type='submit']")
    WebElement proceedBtn;

    public void recharge(String mobileNumber, String rechargeAmount){
        mobileNumberField.sendKeys(mobileNumber);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(selectOperator));
        selectOperator.click();

        WebElement operatorDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("telecom-operator"));
        Select dropDownOperator = new Select(operatorDropdown);
        dropDownOperator.selectByIndex(5);
        //dropDownOperator.getFirstSelectedOption().click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(connectionType));
        connectionType.click();

        WebElement connectionDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("connection-type"));
        Select dropDownConnection = new Select(connectionDropdown);
        dropDownConnection.selectByIndex(1);

        amount.sendKeys(rechargeAmount);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(proceedBtn));
        proceedBtn.click();
    }
}

Base Test:
package pages;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BaseTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup(){
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https:");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }
}

Login Test:
package pages;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testLogin() throws InterruptedException {
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.Login("01791557029", "123456");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}

Recharge Test:
package pages;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RechargeTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void testRecharge(){
        RechargePage rechargePage = new RechargePage(driver);

        rechargePage.recharge("01687663220", "100");
    }
}

And here is my TestNG xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite" verbose="2" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test Cases">
        <classes>
            <class name="pages.LoginTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testLogin"/>
                </methods>
            </class>

            <class name="pages.RechargeTest">
                <methods>
                <include name="testRecharge"/>
                </methods>
            </class>

        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The issue lies in your @BeforeSuite setup. Since you're initializing the WebDriver at the suite level, the same driver instance is shared across all tests, causing conflicts in parallel execution.
To fix this, move the WebDriver initialization to @BeforeClass (or @BeforeMethod if you need a new browser instance per test). Here's the updated code:
public class BaseTest {

protected WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

}

that is exactly the same code that I have!!

no - it is not. your code has before and after suite which basically means that the driver instance is initiated only one time, instead try to use BeforeClass and AfterClass so it initiates and quits the driver instance for each test class.
